# Having user add buttons to app within the app itself

Tags: android

I am building an app where I need to have a settings where the user within their account can add their own custom buttons on the screen.

I have built the activity where the buttons will go but cannot find anything online with reference on how to do this.

Its a point of sale app, so the user goes to settings to add their inventory and the buttons will appear in the register activity.

Any help would be appreciated.

Let me know if I'm not specific enough.

Edit: I want to have my app do the user "john" goes into settings, clicks add items, inputs the name price etc, and a button will appear on the 'register' activity from the info "john" provided

Edit 2: I am finding some info on adding the buttons programatically, how would I code the java for my layout.

I have my activity split into 3 sections 2 on top and 1 on bottom, the buttons will go on the bottom.

[Here is the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ipg3d.png)

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more information; your question is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select your layout that will contain your buttons, from your XML.

Then after you gather the user input (button text, button action) you can write this :

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourLayout);
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setText("hit me!");
layout.add(button);
```

"this" is your activity, so use getActivity() if you're in a fragment.

If your container is not a LinearLayout, you will have to fight with LayoutParam, you will find more on official documentation.

BTW, this is a rather common question, you could find your answer with these keywords on google : "android how to add button programmatically"

Comment: Happens to everyone :-) Don't forget to accept the question if it is solved